# Check wireless link quality under the Linux

Tags: linux

I want to pragmatically check wireless link quality (in C code and in bash script). Using `iwconfig` tool I get current value represented as fraction e.g 47/100. The problem is that, denominators are different for many wifi cards (on my laptop this denominator equals to 100 and on embedded device IGEP Module I'm working on this denominator equals to 70).

I know that I can check current signal quality in `/proc/net/wireless`, bu I don't know where to check denominator value. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't get the question... but from what I understand, you could simply normalize output of iwconfig or iwlist. Both of these commands output denominator [] and nominator ().

1) x1 = 100 * (47) / [100] = 47%

2) x2 = 100 * (47) / [70] = 67%

both x1 and x2 are represented in same unit of measurement. And you can use these numbers to display signal strength bar or whatever it is used for in your application.

re-reading your question, it seems I my answer is not relevant at all. I'm sorry. But can't you use output of iwconfig for your app?